# iPhone UIWebView touch cause Toolbar to appear

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview

I am trying to have a UI which is a full screen UIWebView. When the view is touched the tool bar appears.

I can do everything but get the touchend event in the UIWebView. I have tried putting a UIColor.Clear'd UIView ontop and catching TouchEnd there and passing it on, but would like a better solution.

I understand that we are not supposed to subclass the UIWebView from the docs.

Ideas?

Comment: What's wrong the clear view solution?  That's what I would have done?  What is a "better solution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. Simple have the HTML in the UIWebView send a message to the client via a document.location = "SomeCommandName"

Then catch this in code and toggle the view as needed.

Much simpler.

Comment: Show examples please!
Wwhat do you mean document.location?